# Error in advanced SQL in outsystems

Tags: outsystems

I am writing Advanced SQL query but Syntax error is occurring.
I showed in below image. Please help me

[image]

Comment: Try removing the '\*'. Read up on the syntax for DELETE statements. You are always deleting the full record, so you do not need to specify columns to delete (no, not even '\*' for 'all columns')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove * after delete, by default it will delete all rows from table